# Excel index and match formula not working as expected

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula

I am trying to use Index and match function of the excel to get the value of a column

I have two tabs in excel as below:

```
tab1
    Component      Complexity       Value
    C1               Hard          
    C2               Soft

tab2
    Component     Hard      Soft
    C1             10        20
    C2             5         10
```

I have used Index and match to populate the value in tab1 sheet by looking up "component" and "Hard/soft" value in Tab2 sheet using this formular INDEX(tab2!B2:C3,MATCH(1,(A2=tab2!A2:A3)*(B2=tab2!B1:c1),0)) to get 10 and 10 under the value column in tab1 sheet

However the above formula is returning N/A value and the expected values, Can someone let me know what I am doing wrong in the formula

Comment: MATCH array must be one dimension array. Result of (A2=tab2!A2:A3)*(B2=tab2!B1:c1) is 2D array

Answer (score 5):

Assuming a version of Excel without dynamic arrays, try:

[image]

Formula in `C2`:

```
=INDEX($F$2:$G$3,MATCH(A2,E$2:E$3,0),MATCH(B2,F$1:G$1,0))
```

**Note** the importance of semi-absolute referencing here!

A little less verbose, and possible because of numeric input:

```
=SUMIF(E$2:E$3,A2,INDEX(F$2:G$3,,MATCH(B2,F$1:G$1,0)))
```

Comment: To be honest, I would use first option with INDEX and MATCH: clean, direct and simple :)

Comment: Yes btw JvdV Sir;s solutions are always clean direct and simple. Simply Guru of Excel!!

Answer (score 3):

You got many options. I would indeed use INDEX and MATCH as proposed by @JvdV in his answer, but you could do this too:

[image]

Formula in cell C2:

```
=SUMIF($A$7:$A$8,A2,CHOOSE(MATCH(B2,$B$2:$B$3,0),$B$7:$B$8,$C$7:$C$8))
```

Formula in cell H2:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$7:$A$8=F2)*$B$7:$C$8*($B$6:$C$6=G2))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Index/Match/Match` to also include the column lookup

```
=INDEX('tab2'!$A$1:$C$3,MATCH('tab1'!$A2,'tab2'!$A$1:$A$3,0),MATCH('tab1'!$B2,'tab2'!$A$1:$C$1,0))
```

- The first parameter in the `INDEX` formula `'tab2'!$A$1:$C$3` sets
  the array where it needs to look up the row and the column.
- The second parameter in the `INDEX`, being the first `MATCH` formula
  looks for the `Component` row
- The third parameter in the `INDEX`, being the second `MATCH` formula looks for the `Complexity` column that was set in the first parameter